# Chart.js line chart dots/plots disappearing in dynamic data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I am using the line chart from Chart.js , but for some visualizations the plotted dots (the ones that are showing the coordinates ) are disappearing.[image: The Chart with plots/dots]

The chart above is where the dots/plots are visible.

The chart below is the one where the plots/dots are not showing above. I need the plots because there are many data and without those dots/plots it will be really difficult to show those.

[image: The Chart with no Plots]

The code for the above chart is :

```
var AreaChart = new Chart(AreaCharts, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: '1st',
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: '#f39233',
                borderColor: '#f39233',
                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
                fill: false,
            },
            {
                label: '2nd',
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: '#b8de6f',
                borderColor: '#b8de6f',
                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
                fill: false,
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            
            bezierCurve: false,
            scaleShowValues: true,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        padding: 10,
                        fontSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: ''
            },
            
        },
    });
```

The datasets for the charts are dynamic. It is showing well in some charts but in some it is not as expected.

The Code for the filling and updating of the chart.

```
function fillChart() {
    var labelsChart = [];
    var chartData1 = [];
    var chartData2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.n; i++) {
       
        labelsChart.push($scope.dates[i]);
        chartData1.push($scope.p[i]);
        chartData2.push($scope.f[i]);
    }
    
    AreaChart.data.labels = labelsChart;
    AreaChart.data.datasets[0].data = chartData1;
    AreaChart.data.datasets[1].data = chartData2;
    AreaChart.options.title.text = data.Subject;
    AreaChart.update();
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the way you refresh your chart when the data changes. Can you please also share that part of the code?

Comment: @uminder Have added the code. Please let me know when if I am missing anything else.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What version of Chart.js are you using? Make sure you're using the most recent stable version, which is v2.9.4.

Comment: @uminder Ok. I will look into that. Thanks